# How to define an interface that ensures it's children and parent are of the same type as the defined interface

Tags: c#, generics, hierarchy

So I have a working solution for this but I'm just not sure if I overcomplicate things.

Say we have the following two interfaces:

```
public interface IPrototype
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IHierarchicalPrototype : IPrototype
{
    IHierarchicalPrototype Parent { get; set; }
    IList<IHierarchicalPrototype> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose many implementations of `IHierarchicalPrototype` exist, e.g. `IEntityPrototype` or `IFieldPrototype`.

In the above definition the `Parent` could be any `IHierarchicalPrototype` and an `IEntityPrototype`'s `Children` list could contain any `IHierarchicalPrototype`.

What I wanted to make sure of though is that a `IHierarchicalPrototype` can only contain children of its own type. So a `IEntityPrototype`'s `Children` is of type `IList<IEntityPrototype>` and the `Parent` is of type `IEntityPrototype`.

One solution would be to implement `Children` and `Parent` for every prototype that derives from `IHierarchicalPrototype` but there gotta be an easier way!

What I came up with is a solution with generics.

Instead of defining

```
interface IEntityPrototype : IHierarchicalPrototype {}
```

I could define it with generics like this:

```
interface IEntityPrototype : IHierarchicalPrototype<IEntityPrototype>
```

I can't get rid of the redundant generic type parameter though. I want the generic type parameter to always match the interface I am currently defining and would actually only need the above *if I wanted mix prototypes like this* (which I don't)

```
// this will never happen!
interface IEntityPrototype : IHierarchicalPrototype<IFieldPrototype>
```

Here also the generic definition of the `IHierarchicalPrototype` interface

```
public interface IHierarchicalPrototype<THierarchical> : IPrototype
    where THierarchical : IHierarchicalPrototype<THierarchical>
{
    IHierarchicalPrototype<THierarchical> Parent { get; }
    IList<IHierarchicalPrototype<THierarchical>> Children { get; }
}
```

Any alternative or more elegant solutions you can come up with?

Comment: You may want to read Eric Lippert's [Curiouser and curiouser](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/) which discusses the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" and why it doesn't quite work how you might want it to in C#.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wow, that was *very* fast. Thanks so much for this, I didn't know that what I've implemented is actually a pattern. Very insightful. I was indeed asking myself if the benefits of my implementation will in the future outweigh its disadvantages. Though I couldn't quite see what the all downfalls of this pattern were, I now can understand why. If you write up a more thorough answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Some things you just can't enforce....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever I now know that what I have implemented is actually a pattern called [couriously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (CRTP).

[Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/) and [Zp Bappi](http://zpbappi.com/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-csharp/) both wrote about this for people who are interested in more.

> [I]n practice there are times when using this pattern really does pragmatically solve problems in ways that are hard to model otherwise in C#.[...] One reason why people want to do this is to enforce a particular constraint in a type hierarchy.

This exact reason is what I try to achieve with my code.

My doubts about the CRTP are also mentioned in Lippert's post. He advises

> to think very hard before you implement this sort of curious pattern
>   in C#
>
> 1. because it doesn't actually enforce the constraint you think it does
> 2. this is simply because it bakes the noodle of anyone who reads the code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, then this might help.

```
public interface IPrototype
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name{ get; set; }
}

public interface IHierarchicalPrototype<T> : IPrototype where T:IPrototype
{
    T Parent{ get; }
    IList<T> Children { get; }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. `interface IEntityPrototype : IHierarchicalPrototype<IEntityPrototype>` would enable to add any child of `IPrototype` to its `Children`. I want its children to be exclusively of type `IEntityPrototype` though.